# Plot main title in two lines

Tags: r, plotmath

I would like to have the title for the plot in two lines, but this does not work, why? and how can I make it work?

```
CVal<-1 
SumEpsVal<-2 
plot(1:10, main=bquote(paste("C=", .(CVal), " \n ", sum(xi), "=", .(SumEpsVal) )))
```

This here works:

```
plot(1:10, main=paste("C=1", "\n", "SumXi=2"))
```

I guess bquote makes something wrong... (look up ?bquote)
I tried to change environment in bqoute (the where-argument) but I don't know which environment to take.

BTW:

```
plot(1:10, main=bquote(paste("C=", .(CVal), "bla \n ", sum(xi), "=", .(SumEpsVal) )))
```

makes something crazy with the "bla".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The root issue is that plotmath does not support newlines within the 
expressions to be output.

```
Control characters (e.g. \n) are not interpreted in character strings in plotmath, 
  unlike normal plotting.
```

You really need to create and output each line separately.

For example :

```
Lines <- list(bquote(paste("C=", .(CVal))),
              bquote(paste(sum(xi), "=", .(SumEpsVal))))
```

Now output each line The text in the list is converted to expressions do.call

```
mtext(do.call(expression, Lines),side=3,line=0:1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Personally I would use mtext as already suggested. But if you really want it to be a one-liner, you can "cheat" `bquote` by using `atop`:

```
plot(1:10, main=
  bquote(atop(paste("C=",.(CVal)), paste(sum(xi),"=",.(SumEpsVal)))))
```

It even aligns both lines neatly to the center.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this is to use `mtext` to add an additional line under the main title as follows:

```
plot(1:10, main=bquote(paste("C=", .(CVal))))
mtext(bquote(paste(sum(xi), "=", .(SumEpsVal) )),side=3,line=0)
```

There may be a prettier solution, but perhaps this is enough for your needs.