# How to have a new line in a `bquote` expression used with `text`?

Tags: r, data-visualization, plotmath

I want to have a new line in my `bquote` envrionment, how can I do this?

my code:

```
test<-c(1,2,3,4,4.5,3.5,5.6)
test2<-0.033111111
plot(test,c(1:length(test)))

segments(4,0,4,23,col="red",lwd=2)
text(5, 4.5, labels = bquote(Qua[0.99] == .(round(test2,4))),col="red", cex = 1.4)
```

And I want to have a new line after the equal sign, so this should give:

```
VaR_0.99 =

0.03311

and not

    VaR_0.99 = 0.03311
```

I tried it with lines, but it did not work:

```
    test<-c(1,2,3,4,4.5,3.5,5.6)
    test2<-0.033111111
    lines<-list(bquote(Qua[0.99] == ),bquote(.(round(test2,4))))
    plot(test,c(1:length(test)))

    segments(4,0,4,23,col="red",lwd=2)
    text(5, 4.5, labels =lines ,col="red", cex = 1.4)
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198170/combining-expression-with-n/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136311/plot-main-title-in-two-lines)?

Comment: I tried it with lists, but it did not work! @plannapus

Comment: You cannot have a trailing `"=="`. Need to put something: either phantom(0)` or `" "` after the `==`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the errors was noted above in my comment to the questioner. R expressions get parsed so they need to be syntactically valid. Since "==" is a two-argument function it cannot be the final item in an expression. The `phantom` function serves as a placeholder that is non-printing. Could also have been an empty character value (`""`). Since there was no "outside" value that needed to be evaluated, I just used `expression()` rather than `bquote()` for the first argument in the expression list.

(Note: that expressions in R behave as lists so that `c()` succeeds in appending language items to a single element expression and `list()` is not needed, and in fact was harmful in this situation. There is another subtlety in that `bquote` does not return an "expression"-classed result but rather a "call". It may need to be wrapped with `as.expression` if a true "expression" is needed as was the case here. I've seen R savants use an `lapply( . , as.expression)` to return an expression list in similar situations.)

The other one was more a semantic error than a syntactic one. You need to give an explicit y location for the second `bquote` expression. Pretty much all of the important arguments of text are vector-capable but there doesn't appear to be implicit up-(or down-)indexing for the y values:

```
test <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 5.6)
test2 <- 0.033111111
lines <- c( expression(Qua[0.99] == phantom(0)) ,
           bquote(.(round(test2,4)))
          )
plot(test,c(1:length(test)))

segments(4,0,4,23,col="red",lwd=2)
text(5, c(4.5, 4), labels =lines ,col="red", cex = 1.4)
```

[image]

I have used the `atop` suggestion myself in the past, even suggesting it on Rhelp, but I think the approach above generalizes better to three or more expressions and allows more control over positioning. `atop` also silently reduces font sizes, so if you went the nested atop route for a three expression task, it might need to be `atop( atop(..., ...), atop(..., phantom() )` to keep the sizes uniform.

If you include `adj=0` in `text`-call arguments list you get left justification. Tested in the code for the code above.

Answer (score 11):

For instance, using `atop`:

```
test<-c(1,2,3,4,4.5,3.5,5.6)
test2<-0.033111111
plot(test,c(1:length(test)))

segments(4,0,4,23,col="red",lwd=2)
text(5, 4.5, 
     labels = bquote(atop(Qua[0.99] == phantom(), .(round(test2,4)))),
     col="red", cex = 1.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this but left aligned. After searching for solutions I ended up using two `text()` calls set up to put the text 0.25 inch apart and 0.25 in from top regardless of the plot dimensions.

```
plot(1:100)
r2 <- 40.2
rmse <- 0.6
ll = bquote(paste(italic(R)^2," = ",.(r2),"  RMSE = ",.(rmse)))
val=0.25*diff(par('usr')[3:4])/par('pin')[2]
text(par('usr')[1], par('usr')[4] - val, pos=4, labels=ll)
text(par('usr')[1], par('usr')[4] - 2*val, pos=4, labels="Model A")
```

[Image produced by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKtNm.png)

Comment: If you add `adj=0` to a text-call argument list you get left justification. Tested in the code for the accepted answer.