# Advanced legend in R: Plot

Tags: r, plot, expression, legend, plotmath

This is a following up question of this question:
[How to have a new line in a `bquote` expression used with `text`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663535/r-plot-new-line-in-bquote)

But now I have it in a legend and this seems to change the things.

I tried the following:

```
test<-c(10:1)
dummy1<-0.004323423
dummy2<-0.054
dummy3<-0.032
plot(test,c(1:10))
legend("topright", 
 legend=c(bquote(Qua_0,99^normal == .(round(dummy1,4))),bquote(Qua_0,95^normal == .(round(dummy2,4))),bquote(Qua_0,99^t == .(round(dummy3,4)))),
 bty = "n",lwd=2, cex=1, col=c("red","black","darkgreen"), lty=c(1,3,5))
```

So, I want to have

1. The expression correct, so that the index 0,95 is correctly written and also the power ^ correclty
2. linebreak after the equal sign
3. colored text, the same as the lign, so the first would be in red

I tried to implement the answers of the already existing posts but I did not figured it out, atop is also not working.

Comment: Check out [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300449/1478381) to one of my questions by @agstudy. I think it might help you out

Comment: @SimonO101 mh no, I cannot figure it out....

Comment: @SimonO101 That works because the solution plots two expressions on different lines. You can't do that in a legend as each entry must be on a single "line" and there can only be one expression per legend entry.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson ok thanks, what should I do now?

Comment: Is that `0.95` where you have `0,95` - i.e. you mean a decimal marker and are just in a strange locale ;-)

Comment: @GavinSimpson yeah, but this does not change anything.....

Comment: Yes, it does. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a vector of 3 expressions, and use `substitute` to create the appropriate dummy values. Note that I am using `as.expression` so that they are not immediately evaluated, and the use of `atop` for the line break. Then use that vector when calling `legend`:

```
v <- c(
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[0.99]^normal == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy1,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[0.95]^normal == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy2,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[0.99]^t == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy3,4))))
)
cols <- c("red","black","darkgreen")
legend("topright", legend=v, bty = "n",lwd=2, cex=1, col=cols, text.col=cols, lty=c(1,3,5))
```

The color of the text is set with `text.col`.
[image]

If you want to stick to the use of `bquote` rather than `substitute`:

```
 v <- c(
  as.expression(bquote(atop(Qua[0.99]^normal == "", .(round(dummy1,4))))),
  as.expression(bquote(atop(Qua[0.95]^normal == "", .(round(dummy2,4))))),
  as.expression(bquote(atop(Qua[0.99]^t == "", .(round(dummy3,4)))))
 )
```

To make the *normal* and *0.99* bold, you can use `bold` in the expression:

```
v <- c(
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[bold(0.99)]^bold(normal) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy1,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[bold(0.95)]^bold(normal) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy2,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[bold(0.99)]^bold(t) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy3,4))))
)
```

But the *0.99* will not be very bold actually:
[image]

You can try with text in normal size using `textstyle`:

```
v <- c(
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[textstyle(0.99)]^textstyle(normal) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy1,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[textstyle(0.95)]^textstyle(normal) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy2,4)))),
 as.expression(substitute(atop(Qua[textstyle(0.99)]^textstyle(t) == "", dummy), list(dummy=round(dummy3,4))))
)
```

and get this:
[image]

Comment: ok thanks, but how can I get a linebreak after the equal sign and the text color?

Comment: @StatTistician the only way to do this in a legend is to use the `atop` plotmath function. See how this is used in my answer.

Comment: You can "fix" the spacing the spacing issue between legend elements by adding `y.intersp = 2` to the legend call.

Comment: @GavinSimpson one more question: how can I increase the "normal" and the "0.95"? Increasing cex in legend call increases everything, but I want to increase or write the "normal" and "0.95" more bold?

Comment: @caerolus maybe you also know how to increase the "normal" and the "0.95" letters?

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly using plotmath - one option but it is a hack might be to play around with the `textstyle()` and `scriptstyle()` plotmath functions in combination with `cex`. For example, you could put everything **except** "normal" and "0.95" in `scriptstyle()` wrappings, and then use `cex` to increase the overall font size again. The smaller font for the sub- and superscript is the normal convention in mathmathical typsetting, hence this is what `plotmath` does.

Comment: @StatTistician Added it at the end of the answer

Answer (score 5):

There are several things that were needed here, but the main one is getting the 3 expressions in a suitable format - simply `c`-ing them together doesn't work. For that I create a list of expressions and then `sapply` the `as.expression` function over that list to get a "vector of expressions".

I use the plotmath function `atop` to get a "linebreak"; this places its arguments, one on top of the other.

To get the `0,95` part, which I presume is just `0.95` but in your locale, on my machine I had to use the layout function `*` with a literal `","` to juxtapose the `0` and the `95`. If this is just to write a decimal then in other locales that use `.` as the decimal separator, this would not be necessary. I suspect that in your locale, you can use the second version below but writing `[0,99]` instead of `[0.99]`, but I don't know.

If you just put

```
bquote(atop(foo_0.99^normal ==, .round(bar, 4)))
```

you'd just get an error:

```
> bquote(atop(foo_0.99^normal ==, .round(bar, 4)))
Error: unexpected ',' in "bquote(atop(foo_0.99^normal ==,"
```

This is because the right hand side of the `==` function/operator is missing. As you don't want anything after the `==` (on the current line!), you need to use something that doesn't add extra space but provides a valid right hand side for `==`. Here I use `phantom()` which acts as a placeholder but leaves no space (as I supply it no argument). But you can also use `== ""`, substituting `""` for `phantom()`.

To get the text in the same colour as the line, use the `text.col` argument.

Here is the thing in full with all your requests catered for (after a fashion):

```
test <- 10:1
dummy1 <- 0.004323423
dummy2 <- 0.054
dummy3 <- 0.032
plot(test, 1:10)

## list of expressions
exprs <-
  list(bquote(atop(Qua_0 * "," * 99^normal == phantom(), .(round(dummy1, 4)))),
       bquote(atop(Qua_0 * "," * 95^normal == phantom(), .(round(dummy2, 4)))),
       bquote(atop(Qua_0 * "," * 99^t == phantom(), .(round(dummy3, 4)))))
## fudge to get them as an expression vector
exprs <- sapply(exprs, as.expression)

cols <- c("red", "black", "darkgreen")
legend("topright", legend = exprs, bty = "n", lwd = 2, cex = 1, col = cols,
       lty=c(1,3,5), text.col = cols)
```

It looks like you are using the LaTeX `_` to get superscript. In plotmath you need `[ ]`. 
You'll also note that this is not quite so nice typographically --- there isn't enough space between the legend entries but some space between the elements within a single entry. This is because we are abusing `atop` to fake the newline. We can deal with that using the `y.intersp` argument of `legend`. Increasing it to `2` gives sufficient space.

Combining this, I would do the following to meet all your requirements:

```
plot(test, 1:10)

## list of expressions
exprs <-
  list(bquote(atop(Qua[0.99]^normal == phantom(), .(round(dummy1, 4)))),
       bquote(atop(Qua[0.95]^normal == phantom(), .(round(dummy2, 4)))),
       bquote(atop(Qua[0.99]^t == phantom(), .(round(dummy3, 4)))))
## fudge to get them as an expression vector
exprs <- sapply(exprs, as.expression)

cols <- c("red", "black", "darkgreen")
legend("topright", legend = exprs, bty = "n", lwd = 2, cex = 1, col = cols,
       lty=c(1,3,5), text.col = cols, y.intersp = 2)
```

This produces:

[image]