# Axis title containing texts with exponents

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, plotmath

I'm using `ggplot2` to plot a chart. I want to add an exponent to a text within the Y-axis title, so it would look like this:

Energy (kcal ∙ mol-1)

I usually write the axis title text inside `labs ()` and its aesthetic inside `theme (axis.title.y = element_text ())`. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361774/exponents-in-ggplot2-title#:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A) answer, but I couldn't understand any of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a duplicate question. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r) for detailed answers.

You can build an expression

```
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1)) + 
  labs(y=expression('Energy (kcal '~mol^-1*')'))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Also, for future reference: when you use `expression ()` inside `labs ()`, the font face of your axis title won't show in bold even if you specify it in `theme (axis.title.y = element_text ())` . You'll actually have to specify it inside `expression ()` like this:

`labs (y = expression (bold ("Energy (kcal ∙ mol"^-1*")")))`