# Typing long text in legend with automatic line return and mathematical notation in R

Tags: r, text, annotations

I'm typing text in a legend which explains something I'm doing in a plot. I'd like to add some mathematical equations in the text but it doesn't work when I want to use the strwrap function (which cuts the text according to a fixed length).

```
plot(1:10)
text.explain = "This is some quite long text where I want to add math notation stuff like z bar_i and continue to explain other stuff adding further math notation like this (W bar_i), but it is not doing what I want"
legend(x =1, y = 9,
  legend = paste0(strwrap(text.explain, 37), collapse = "\n"), bty = "n")

legend(x =6, y = 5,
  legend = paste0(strwrap(bquote(.(text.explain)), 37), collapse = "\n"), bty = "n")
```

[image]

I saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663535/how-to-have-a-new-line-in-a-bquote-expression-used-with-text), but would like to add line returns automatically and not have multiple `expression`, and `bquote` functions to type the text. I also want the `z bar_i` and `W bar_i` to be $$bar{z}_i$$ and $$bar{W}_i$$ (like in math notation).

Is there a way to do that?

I've been trying stuff out and this is the closest:

```
plot(1:10)
text.explain = "This is some quite long text where I want to add math notation stuff like z bar_i and continue to explain other stuff adding further math notation like this (W bar_i), but it is not doing what I want"

legend(x =6, y = 5,
       legend = paste0(strwrap(bquote(.(text.explain)), 37), collapse = "\n"), bty = "n")
title = list("This is some quite long text where I want to",
             bquote("add math notation stuff like"~bar(z)~"and continue"),
             "to explain other stuff adding further math",
             bquote("notation like this"~bar(W)~", but it is not "),
             "doing what I want.")
leg = do.call(expression, title)
legend(x =1, y = 8,
       y.intersp = 1.7,
       legend =  leg
       , bty = "n")
```

But it is not doing it automatically based on a fixed character length (as in `strwrap`)...

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you can't just mix expressions and plain text in string labels. If you want any of the `plotmath` expressions to work, you need everything to be an expression. Unfortunately expressions don't have any native line-wrap support. You might be able to write a function to help you write the multiple expressions lines, but you would need a way to indicate which parts should be text and which parts should be mathematical expressions. It's not clear from your example that finding the delineation would be easy.

Comment: Exactly, I was wondering if there could be a way to do that, but perhaps, it's only possible to do it manually at the moment...

Comment: There's no real way to map a plotmath expression to a number of characters so you can't really wrap based on string width from the R side of things. I think all that stuff is figured out in the C code for the graphics device but as far as I know you don't have access to that in R code.