# R plot title with greek letter, newline and variable value

Tags: string, r, plot, expression, special-characters

I am trying to plot a title, a greek character and as well the mean of a variable. I want my plot title to look something like this (but centered)

**Title**

**μ=1.2**

I made a few attepmts:

```
d <- rnorm(100)
hist(d, main=expression(paste("Title\n", mu, "=", mean(d))))
hist(d, main=expression(paste("Title\n", mu, "=", mymean), list(mymean=mean(d))))
hist(d, main=paste(expression(paste("Title\n", mu, "="), mean(d))))
hist(d, main=expression(atop("Title", substitute(mu, "=", mymean, list(mymean=mean(d))))))
hist(d, main=expression("Title\n", substitute(mu, "=", mymean, list(mymean=mean(d)))))
```

but I don't know how to use `expression` or `substitute` correctly in the title. I know that `mtext` would be a possibility, but it should work using the main= argument...?

Comment: i think the three requirements are incompatible, unless you use unicode for mu: `plot(1,1, main=paste("Title\n\U03BC=",1.2))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot main title in two lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136311/plot-main-title-in-two-lines)

Comment: Looks similar, I must have overlooked this when I asked the question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with `atop`:

```
hist(d, main=bquote(atop(Title,mu==.(mean(d)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `plain()` function to specify normal text and `*`, `~` and `~~` as a spacers:

```
mtext(main=bquote(plain("Observation at pH ") ~ .(pH) ~~ plain(" [") *  mu * plain("M]")))
```

This is explained somewhat cryptically in `?plain` (which translates into help regarding plain, when typed in the R command line prompt). You will then get the help page `Mathematical Annotation in R`, then search for plain in that page.