# How to incorporate varying title and variable values in plot labels in loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create numerous plots with varying parameter values.  When I submit the code below:

---

```
for(i in mars){
    for(j in 1:5){
        negRets <- -table1.matrix[,j]
        tauSigma <- gpd(negRets,threshold=i)
        tau <- tauSigma$par.ests[1]
        sigma <- tauSigma$par.ests[2]
        #cat("For ", reitPort[j], "portfolio and MAR=", i, "the parameter estimats are:", "\n")
        #cat("Tau= ", tau, "Sigma= ", sigma, "\n")
        exceedence.vector <- sort(subset(negRets, negRets > i))
        returns.sorted <- sort(negRets)
        pdf(paste("C:\\Users\\John Broussard\\Dropbox\\evtHandbookProject\\figuresTables\\mar_",i,"_",reitPort[j],".pdf",sep=""))
            plot(returns.sorted, dgpd(returns.sorted, xi = tau, beta = sigma), type ="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,90))
            title(main=cat("Tau= ", tau, " Sigma= ", sigma), ylab=" ")
        dev.off()
        #print(j)
        #print(i)
    }
}
```

---

The plots are written to the files, but no title, and the y-axis label contains "xi=tau," not the value for xi submited in the plot code.

How do I get a title and the values of the parameters being using for the plots to be incorporated into the individual files?

Comment: main = paste(file[i], any other variables not quoted, "StaticWordsinTitleQuoted", sep = "")

Comment: Do you want Greek letters for tau and sigma? Furthermore dgpd appears to be a function froma package not loaded by that code.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `paste()` function rather than the `cat()` function. The `cat()` function outputs an object while `paste()` concatenates a vector after converting to a character.

```
plot(returns.sorted, dgpd(returns.sorted, xi = tau, beta = sigma), 
    type ="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,90),
    main = paste("Tau= ", tau, " Sigma= ", sigma), ylab=" ")
```

If you want greek letters see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044800/adding-greek-character-to-axis-title) question or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947945/r-plot-title-with-greek-letter-newline-and-variable-value) question.