# How to use more than one expression in a row

Tags: r, plot, expression, plotmath

I am new to R and I am trying to figure out, how to write something like *"This is my plot for (\n)8 <=(less than or equal) x <= 10"* in my plot-title.

I tried something like this:

```
plot(1:10, main="Hey, guys, this is my plot for \n")
mtext(c(expression(8 <= x),expression(x <= 10), side=3)
```

This gives not exactly what I want but "8 (less or equal) x x (less or equal) 10", and those two expressions are printed in a line below the main title, (which is pretty cool) but in the same place, which is pretty much useless :)

I also tried:

```
plot(1:10, main=bquote(paste(8 <= x, x <= 10, sep=",")))
```

What kind of does what I want (except the seperator seems to be completely ignored), but I cant add further text. Output: "8 (less or equal) xx (less or equal) 10".

And when I tried

```
plot(1:10, main=paste("x",bquote(paste(x <= 8,z <= 10,sep=" ")),sep=" "))
```

the output irritated me completely: the title was: "xpaste (\n) x x <= 8 (\n) x z <= 10 (\n) x" (the (\n) is a line break, the other characters are exactly what is printed)

So is there a possibility to print expressions with more than one operator?

Answer (score 4):

```
heyTitle <- bquote(atop(
    "Hey, guys, this is my plot for",
    {8 <=x}*phantom()<=10
    ))

plot(1:10, main=heyTitle)
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137598/2343633) for the `atop()` trick.

EDIT: Here is the figure

EDIT 2: borrowing from [another answer by G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520016/2343633) to use brackets to fix spacing.

[image]

Comment: I thank both of you. Now I just need to decide which solution I will use.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 plot( 1:10, main = ~ bold(atop("Hey, guys, this is my plot for", {"8" <= x} <= "10")))
```

On the `windows()` device it looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

**REVISED** spacing and made 2nd line a bit larger to match first line. Added rbatt's `atop` idea. Further simplification.

Comment: Nice use of {} to deal with spacing. I'm going to use your technique there to update my answer – hope you don't mind (I previously used `8 <=~x~phantom()<=10`, now use `{8 <=x}*phantom()<=10`

Comment: OK. I will trade you a {} for an `atop`.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are a bit goofy, but here is how you can do that

```
plot(1:10, main="Hey, guys, this is my plot for \n")
mtext(expression(paste(8 <= x,", ",x <= 10)), side=3)
```

To get a vector of expressions, you just use `expression(exp1,exp2,exp3)`. No need to bother with `c()` or `list()`. And then to mix expressions with text, `paste()` often comes in handy. Without `paste` to combine them as one expression, they will plot on top of each other at the same location.

Comment: As an addition to MrFlick's answer, if only one x was wanted, which is how I took the question:

`plot(1:10, main="Hey, guys, this is my plot for \n")
mtext(expression(paste(8 <= x,"" <= 10)), side=3)`