# Plot-Title whith several expressions was fine, but doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, plot, metric

I once asked the following question on stackoverflow:

[Old Question to ask for plot-title with several expressions in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519142/how-to-use-more-than-one-expression-in-a-row[1])
The following answer worked fine for me:

```
title1 <- bquote(atop("Berechnete  über gemessener Wellenanlaufrichtung für",
                    {U <= "4 m/s"}))   

plot(1:10, main=title1)
```

I implemented it in a function.
Today I wanted to use the function and I got the following error message:

```
heyTitle <- bquote(atop(
           "Hey, guys, this is my plot for",
           {8 <=x}*phantom()<=10
           ))

plot(1:10, main=heyTitle)
>
Error in title(...) : 
   Metric information not available for this family/device
```

I absolutely don't knwo what to do to get this solution working again...

Comment: Works for me. What Version/OS? What device are you writing to?

Comment: i am using R-Version 3.1.0, (the moment it worked was on an older R-Version i think) OS: Windows (here changed nothing since last time). i am writing to no device, i just want to "plot"

Comment: alright, it isn't satisfying, but i used my linux-laptop whith an older R-Version (2.15.1) and it worked... i am happy now, but any suggestions how i had to do this would be nice :)