# In R, how to horizontally align strings and math expressions appearing on separate rows in plot titles

Tags: r, plotmath

I need to combine character strings and mathematical expressions to form the titles of plots. I need the strings and expressions to appear on separate rows. I achieve this by inserting "\n" symbols where needed in the character strings. However, the strings and expressions do not appear horizontally aligned - the expressions are horizontally shifted to the right relative to the expressions. How can I make them horizontally aligned?

Reproducible code:

```
plot( runif(10), runif(10) )
title( expression( "Hello world\n" ~ 64 %/% 8 %/% 8 ) )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136311/plot-main-title-in-two-lines